# HTML Open Web Page at the Bottom From Link

Tags: html

I would like to be able to click a link and have the new web page open looking at the bottom not the top. I am new to HTML and have no clue how to approach this, any advise would help.

I am using a basic link in a unordered list

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place an anchor in your target page and link directly to that.

So something like this in index.html (at the bottom):

```
<a name="bottom"></a>
```

And then your link like this:

```
<li><a href="index.html#bottom">Home</a></li>
```

You may have to link to the full URL of the page for it to work properly
(for example: `http://www.yourdomain.com/index.html#bottom`).

Answer (score 2):

If you have no access to the backend, you can just add "/#[id of an element on the webpage]" to the URL of the page.

For instance, you can inspect the footer and find out the ID attached to it. For this webpage that you're currently on, the ID assigned is "#footer" (right click and inspect it to check). So all you need to do is add **/#footer** to the end of the URL.

So, to load this page looking at the bottom, use the URL: [HTML Open Web Page at the Bottom From Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055714/html-open-web-page-at-the-bottom-from-link/#footer)

Works for all pages in the World Wide Web.

Comment: That's amazing, I never knew one could use CSS ids as anchor tags without providing explicit name tags, [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name) is deprecated now in favour of your approach